# webview with multi pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

Is there a sample that demonstrate the webview multi-page access, just like safari multi web page selection?
I try to find some hints but no result

Welcome any comment

Comment: You can open only one page at a time in webview. the webview opens html pages like safari but it has limited functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement that yourself. You do this with a scrollview to pick a webpage, grab a screnshot of the current webpage shown to put into the selection screen.